# How to run the statement only after the previous statement completes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following jQuery / jQuery mobile statements

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer(   
    "change", $article1, {transition: "slide", reverse: true}  ); 

contentpart2.hide();    $contentpart3.hide();
```

The above statements run correctly, but it would be even better if

```
contentpart2.hide();    $contentpart3.hide();
```

execute only when the previous statement completes.

How can I do that?   Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!!

**UPDATE**

Did I do it the right way?

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer(   "change" , 
                                        $article1 , 
                                        { transition: "slide", reverse: true }  ,
                                        function( ) 
                                        {   
                                             $contentpart2.hide();  
                                             $contentpart3.hide();  
                                        }   
                                             ); slideID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show) (and forgive me, I haven't used jQuery Mobile extensively), the `pagecontainershow` event is fired on the pagecontainer widget's element. So you can add that code there, as well as check to make sure it's the correct page (make sure `prevPage` and `toPage` are correct, in case this is code for a special-case.

Comment: I did it according to your advice and the advice from the guy below.  Does the syntax look correct?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/8d024xkf/)

Use the following:

```
$('.selector1').hide(function() {
    $('.selector2').hide();
});
```